# How to span the kafka partitions across multiple VM's?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am familiar with basic kafka system. I want to span a single kafka instance across 2 VM's such that some partitions are in one VM and some more in another VM. Please tell me how to configure this kind of system.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "to span kafka instance across 2 VMs" ? What you can due is having two different Kafka instances running on the 2 VMs. They should be configured in order to connect to the same Zookeeper cluster. When you create a new topic with a specific number of partitions, Kafka will span such partitions over the 2 VMs.